# Getting something unique about user's computer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the idea:
If I can get something unique about a computer with JavaScript from an HTML page (probably the MAC address), then can I use this data as another security check?
Is that possible?

I am not going to check the computer at client side, i am going to send it to server to check. If nothing sent, user will be blocked. So it is not something that any developer+firebug combination can bypass. I just want to send one more string with username and password which is unique to computer and no one else knows if they don't entered to the system from that computer. Like a password hidden from user itself.

Comment: Check this out: https://panopticlick.eff.org, does a 'browser fingerprint test' to tell you how unique your browser configuration is.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: GREAT! :D but still not enough :(

Comment: You might get better responses if you clarify your question.  Specifically that you are looking for an _authentication_ system, can use HTML 5 file-system calls and that the users will be opting in and fully aware of the filesystem access requirement.  At first glance, I thought this sounded like you were just trying to hack your way through the browser sandbox into private computers without user knowledge.

Comment: no it's not like i am trying to hack into anyones system without their permission. I have doubt's with file sending and checking system because it needs user interaction, and especially users mustn't lose the file i sent, which is very likely. I may ask for permission, they are going to give the permission BUT more than clicking a button is far more complex for average user, especially in this APPLE era

Comment: I get it now - and FWIW agree that authorization is a serious UX issue.  I'm glad you were trying to generate usable alternatives.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Only allowing users to be able to log in from specific machines, or making it harder for unauthorized users to log in? If it is the second one, given that someone has stolen a user name and password, they can probably also get whatever machine fingerprint you use and send that from their own machine.

Comment: My servers are getting irrelevant even from other countries -which i think MIGHT be someone trying to access the system(no google etc, but random people)- so, it is a really good option if i can force them to give me something that they can't reach, which is not a password that a user will select(can be cracked from very very long distances, and most of my users are +40 people so they will choose something like 123789), but a 1000 character random string which is pretty hard to hack. So i am trying to seal my app, and this is just an idea

Comment: @gkaykck: Interesting, but consider these scenarios: I have accidentally deleted the unique file from my computer/I got a new computer/I lost all data/I'm working from two different computers at different locations. *Now* what? My data wasn't hacked or stolen, I still know my username and password, except I can't login because my login is tied to the one piece of unique data which is not accessible (maybe it doesn't even exist anymore).

Comment: That actually starts to look like you want client-side SSL certificates - see my (now edited) answer.

Comment: @Piskvor, we have a call center for that kind of stuff, and the users i am mentioning are companies, so i can verify them and reset their login system

Comment: @Piskvor, i don't need ssl, i was just wondering if i can build a system like that

Comment: @gkaykck: Are you sure you don't? Although SSL's most known function is encrypting the data in transit (which is not your concern here), its lesser-known function is **identifying the server and (optionally) the client** - and identifying the client seems to be your concern.

Comment: most relevant answer came from piskvor, so i selected it, but i actually want this to become a community wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can try using a tracking cookie; note however that such mechanisms are considered transient (e.g. cookies can be erased). In-browser JavaScript is sandboxed so that it does not have access to components outside the page. Note also that any feeling of security you'll gain with JavaScript is illusory - the script runs on the client side, where it can be modified (therefore there's no way to tell whether the "unique" piece of data is genuine or faked) or disabled altogether.
- If you're trying to prevent random people from hacking at your app, you may want to ban them after a certain number of failed attempts. This will not get you any security, it's more of a flytrap - it limits the annoyances somewhat.
- Finally, if you want actual security, go for HTTPS with real (NOT self-signed) server certificates and **client-side certificates** - see e.g. [this](http://lenss.nl/2011/02/apache-ssl-client-side-certificate-data-in-php/) for an implementation (that example, however, uses self-signed server certificates, which is not very secure). This is a mechanism that is well-implemented in the browser itself, and provides you with a somewhat secure system (complete with a secure keystore) of identifying your users (as opposed to a fundamentally flawed JS "security", or relying on user-readable files). Oh, and your data is encrypted while on the wire, that's a bonus.

SSL actually does what you're asking for: verifies that the client machine has a certificate issued to that user. This mechanism works inside the browser, not just inside the webpage; thus, it is much harder to subvert this than an in-page JavaScript. It stores a large unique identifier (clientside certificate) in a secure way, and it can *prove* to the server that it actually has that identifier - which is pretty much your initial requirement.

(Incidentally, using SSL, the data will be protected in transit, and the client can validate the server's identity; those weren't your requirements, but they're more or less necessary to assure that you're actually talking to the real client and real server)

Comment: the script runs at client side but i just want that script to send me something unique about the computer, rest is handled on server

Comment: @gkayck: So, assuming there would be a `getSomethingUnique()` function in JS, what would prevent the user from overriding that function so that it returned fake data? (hint: nothing)

Comment: @gkaykck What's to stop someone to grabbing the unique code from one machine and then sending that from another machine to impersonate the former? You have no way to guarantee that the client is actually running your script at all.

Comment: @Piskovr, i am just going to send another login data, there will be also USERNAME and PASSWORD AND UNIQUE DATA. So if no unique data, user can't login the system. Why everyone thinks i am going to check it INSIDE javascript, it is a mistake that even a beginner won't make. I am going to SEND the unique data with login details, then check  it at server

Comment: @gkaykck: I'm not thinking you'll be *checking* it inside JS. You'll be *getting* it through JS, and that's a weak spot. This is my question: If the data returned from call to get-a-unique-file is replaced with fake data *on the client*, how will the server know?

Comment: @Piskvor, server cannot know if data is replaced but there will be still username and password. And also how can you guess 1000 char long random string and put it into the function. You have to steal it but it if user lets other people run their computers while logging in, i cannot do anymore. That's their problem.

Comment: @gkaykck: Hmm, but if the system falls back to username+password when the unique key is not found, then the key doesn't really make the system any more secure, as it's not *really* needed to login, no? As for "stupid users" - you're right, there's no cure for that ;)

Comment: :D no, system is not going to fall back if unique key is not found. where did you get that :D i just tried to say that, if anyone uses the computer, the computer that has the key, and tries to enter the system, than username+password will block them. but otherwise, username+password+key is a very hard combination for any hacker that has never touched THE COMPUTER :D

Comment: @gkaykck: I have misunderstood you, then: "server cannot know if data is replaced but there will be still username and password" sounded like that. Sorry about that; you are correct that adding more bits of entropy will slow down a hacking attempt. Anyway, this has been a rather enlightening discussion, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript within a Web browser executes within a sandbox and has no access to the underlying hardware. Besides, MAC addresses aren't guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: as long as i know this is true, but with html5 i can reach to users file with permission, so maybe there is a way. And mac addresses are unique enough i guess

Comment: @gkaykck: 1) MAC addresses are "reasonably" unique, but they aren't files, and 2) a prompt saying "please select this file from your computer" looks very much like spyware, even if it isn't.

Comment: the application is not a free app like twitter, it is a package for sale. So making users select a file is not a problem here, they will trust :D

Comment: Which file are you going to have them select?

Comment: i am not going to make them select any file, but it might be a solution. If i generate a unique key file and make them download it, then while login, i might ask for the file. But not the best solution

Comment: The thing is, they can just as easily clear that key file as they can a tracking cookie - there isn't a _permanent_ way to store the key.

Comment: @gkaykck That sounds very much like a cookie to me. If you're using HTTPS then that should actually be secure.

Comment: @peteorpeter, yes that's true, lost/stolen key files is going to be the biggest problem with that system, so i am looking for something else, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. And you shouldn't implement security with JavaScript only as any competent developer with Firebug will get around it in no time.

Comment: no they cant, because i will send users unique stuff to server, and then check if the machine have the rights to reach my content. So firebug will work if the competent developer can crack anyone's facebook account with their email addresses

Comment: @gkaykck: I use approximately 6 different computers, quite legitimately. User != machine. Also, FB uses a simple username+password auth, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: that is relevant because i am sending an extra data from computer which is not known by others, like password. So with username+password+someDataThatNoOneExceptTheComputerKnows is a good combination for security if you got completely dummy users like me :D

Comment: What I mean is that if you put your authorization logic in client side script, then anyone with Firebug (for example) can easily make all your methods say 'access granted'. If you don't then it obviously does not apply.

Comment: client cannot say access granted man cmon, just read some comments, i am going to grant access at server, not at client