# Utilize Windows Aero Window Color for web

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to replicate a windows 7 window in a webpage. I want to use the user's configured window color on the window border. I have tried `background:ActiveCaption` but windows aero does not sync the aero window color to the xp style Active Title Bar color. Any ideas where else I could capture the color?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with JS/CSS/HTML5, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5898262/586621). You can replicate Windows 7 Aero theme with CSS/JS, just not the specific color that the user is using.

Answer (score 3):

The OS environment data, such as window style settings, are not exposed to the browser. If they were, it could be a potential security threat.