# Best way to get MAC address from web application client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, applet

I am working in a application in which I need to check mac address of the client machine who is accessing my website before giving him any type of authentication. I want to know what is the best way to do this which will be able to provide me MacAddress every time even there are lot of firewalls, proxies etc

I know there are several ways i.e.

1) Using Active X control
2) Using Java Applet
3) Using Certificates

I want to know what are the other ways of doing this and what are their pros and cons.

I am currently using Asp.Net for my development

Comment: Please read the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241857/best-way-to-get-mac-address-from-web-application-client-machine Further: Maybe you should explain what you'd attempt once you had these addresses, there might be a more reliable/secure solution.

Comment: very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898192/getting-something-unique-about-users-computer-with-javascript imho you better find another solution. what should happen if che client has more than one interface? what if the user on the client is spoofing the mac address?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get the client machine MAC address. Because MAC addresses might be stripped from packets when they leave client's local network.

Comment: if this mac address not exist in our database , we will ask them to send otp and once otp is confirmed we will add this mac address to out database for next time authetnication

Comment: One can [spoof MAC address](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spoof+MAC+address), it ain't good for authentication.